# sporfire: calculate the avg per 15 minutes

Tags: average, spotfire

I am a beginner for Spotfire. I have a problem about the average calculation per each 15 mins by calculated column.  A sample table could be like this:

```
id  time-stamp              value
 1  7/1/2016 12:01:01 AM    1.1
 2  7/1/2016 12:05:03 AM    0.9
 3  7/1/2016 12:08:04 AM    1.2
 4  7/1/2016 12:09:06 AM    0.8
 5  7/1/2016 12:12:09 AM    0.4
 6  7/1/2016 12:14:10 AM    0.6
 7  7/1/2016 12:15:12 AM    1.3
 8  7/1/2016 12:18:04 AM    1.4
 9  7/1/2016 12:21:06 AM    0.7
 10 7/1/2016 12:24:09 AM    1.7
 11 7/1/2016 12:31:10 AM    0.5
 12 7/1/2016 12:39:12 AM    1.3
```

I want to calculate the avg value for each 15 mins, the table is already ordered by time.
the final table I want to have is:

```
 time-stamp               Avg
 7/1/2016 12:00:00 AM    0.83333
 7/1/2016 12:15:00 AM    1.275
 7/1/2016 12:30:00 AM    0.9
```

for example, for the first number 0.83333 =(1.1+0.9+1.2+0.8+0.4+0.6)/6

it seems that I should identify an expression of  the calculation for a new table, but how to calculate the avg. for each 15 mins. somebody could help me ?

thanks for your help :)

note: thanks for code @ksp585, but after this, i still have a small problem for it, the cross table just shows the times-stamp until 9:45 PM

[image]

Comment: Store dates/times using an appropriate data type. Then get back to us.

Comment: @Strawberry what makes you think it's not stored as a DATETIME?

Comment: hi , all, the time-stamp column is saved as a DateTime format, but i will check it again tmr :)

Comment: @ZAWD I know it is. Strawberry was just too quick to post a comment of little merit. Spotfire has the ability to display fields differently from their native format. Thus, your field which has AM and PM makes it seem like it is a VARCHAR when it is not. You are fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ ZAWD - I have created a calculated column which groups the timestamp into 4 quarters for an hour. Used this column in the cross table below to calculate average time.

timestamp grouping expression (time_interval):

```
case  
when (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])>0) and (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])<15) then Date([time-stamp]) & " " & Hour([time-stamp]) & ":00" & ":00" 
when (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])=15) and (DatePart("second",[time-stamp])>0) then Date([time-stamp]) & " " & Hour([time-stamp]) & ":15" & ":00" 
when (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])>15) and (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])<30) then Date([time-stamp]) & " " & Hour([time-stamp]) & ":15" & ":00" 
when (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])=30) and (DatePart("second",[time-stamp])>0) then Date([time-stamp]) & " " & Hour([time-stamp]) & ":30" & ":00" 
when (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])>30) and (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])<45) then Date([time-stamp]) & " " & Hour([time-stamp]) & ":30" & ":00" 
when (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])=45) and (DatePart("second",[time-stamp])>0) then Date([time-stamp]) & " " & Hour([time-stamp]) & ":45" & ":00" 
when (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])>45) and (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])<=60) then Date([time-stamp]) & " " & Hour([time-stamp]) & ":45" & ":00" 
when (DatePart("minute",[time-stamp])=0) and (DatePart("second",[time-stamp])>0) then Date([time-stamp]) & " " & Hour([time-stamp]) & ":00" & ":00"
else null end
```

Final Table:

[image]

Tested with a different datetime format:
[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i have tried the code, it works, but still a small question, the time-stamp of my dataset is from 00:00:00 to  23:59:59, the inserted calculated column based on your code is same, but when i create a cross table, it just shows the time until 9PM:45:00. i think it is strange, maybe you have some ideas for it ?

Comment: I have tried the solution with different date formats, all of them giving me the same result. Attached screenshot in my solution. Also, your datatime format is little strange. Could you please custom format it using 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt' from column properties and see if it works?